# How to test Rails Juggernaut in Internet Explorer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, internet-explorer, server-push, juggernaut

I'm having problem with my Rails application. I use [juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/) for server push, which works very nice in Firefox, Opera and Chrome, but it doesn't work at all in IE. It should be compatible with IE6+.

The problem is, that I can't find any debugging tools that can monitor *network* as Firebug does in Firefox. I tried IE debug bar, but there isn't anything about AJAX and network.

I'm running on default juggernaut settings and it doesn't even connect to the push *server*.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem with IE8. IE8 has a "Developer Tools" item in the "Tools" menu (or hit F12 to activate it). I'm seeing errors in the minified `application.js` file.

Comment: Sorry, I read your question too quickly. In my case, it was the combined and minified JavaScript that gave me problems (the IE Developer Tools actually showed me an error in the JavaScript). Switching back to Juggernaut's separate JS files fixed my problem. As for testing the server, I don't have a direct answer for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try using firebug lite http://getfirebug.com/lite.html

Answer (score 0):

firebuglite is good tool.

If you are on a ruby on rails project, use firelite gem

https://rubygems.org/gems/firelite